# JWPlayer No suitable players found error with youtube link

Tags: javascript, youtube, jwplayer

I got a problem with JWPlayer, which happened only lately (means was working with this exact code). I'm getting "No suitable players found" using youtube links. my setup is as follows:

```
   jwplayer("mediaplayer2").setup({
        flashplayer: "php/jwplayer/player.swf",
        file: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IsYAoR7hfPE",
        autostart: true,
        controls: false,
        logo: "http://...",
        "logo.link": "tracker2.php","logo.hide":false,
        controlbar: "over",
        "controlbar.idlehide": "true",
        "controlbar.hide": "true",
        image: "php/jwplayer/preview.jpg",
        screencolor: "000000",
        width: "500",
        height: "300",
        stretching: "fill",
        skin: "php/jwplayer/skins/bekle.zip",
        abouttext: "Flash Player",
        aboutlink: "http://...",
        events: {
            onPause: function() {
                if(success != 1)
                this.play(true);
            },
            onComplete: function() {
                //this.stop();
                //$.post('php/jwplayer/callback.php');
                if(success == 1)
                {
                    this.stop();
                            }

                    },
            onError: function(message)
            {
                alert(message);
                console.log(message);
            },
            onSetupError: function(fallback,message)
            {
                alert(message);
                console.log(message);
            }           

        }
    });
```

how can I fix this?

Comment: Please provide a link to where you are running this.

Comment: right now it's working again though: https://baldaty.gamester.com.tr/facebook/townster/php/jwplayer/player2.php

Comment: Yeah, it works fine. How often does it break?

Comment: it broke today, or i noticed today, not sure. could it be ssl or connection issue? what does this error means on youtube files?

Comment: Usually that error means the file can't be found. Maybe there was a connection issue at the time?

Comment: That's posssible. thanks for the help.

Comment: No problem, any time.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with the youtubevideo you are using, it is a private video. 
To know more on how to embed youtube video in jwplayer check out this

1. [youtube-video-embed](http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1406725-youtube-video-embed)
2. [ehow : play-youtube-videos-jw-player.html](http://www.ehow.co.uk/how_8640508_play-youtube-videos-jw-player.html)

This is the error i am getting in the console

```
Object
message: "Error loading YouTube: Video removed or private"
type: "jwplayerError"
__proto__: Object
```

Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23266528/how-to-embed-youtube-video-in-jw-player) and comments on this question, you can not play private youtube videos in jwplayer.

I have made simple demo to show jwplayer with youtube

Check this [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/hiteshbhilai2010/M2baw/7/)

```
jwplayer("mediaplayer2").setup({

        file: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=efuICQgCWLA",
        autostart: true,
       // controls: false,
        width: "500",
        height: "300",
        stretching: "fill",



    });
```

Also check this trouble shooting guide [here](http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1403682-troubleshooting-your-setup)

> **Error loading YouTube: Video removed or private** This means the YouTube
>   video has been removed (for any reason), or it has been marked as
>   private by the owner of the video.

Comment: This video was public/active at the time the question was asked, but we removed it afterwards. thanks for the answer though.